# Help solving first order discrete differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve the 1st order ODE,

$$x[k+1] + \frac14 x[k] = k\left(-\frac12\right)^k, \quad k\ge 0.$$

I have figured out the homogeneous solution to be $x_h[k] = \alpha\left(-\frac14\right)^k$, but cannot figure out how to go about finding the particular solution $x_p[k]$, so that my general solution is $x[k] = x_h[k] + x_p[k]$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As a curious observer: Is the notation $x[k]$ to denote "$x$ as a function of $k$"?  I've never seen that notation before...

Comment: yes. Like when we denote discrete time signals.

Comment: Try Z-transform!

Comment: This is no differential equation but a finite-difference equation.

Comment: Actually, they are usually called *recurrence equations* or *recurrence relations*.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the RHS (a linear polynomial times an exponential) hints you to try a solution of the same shape,

$$x_k=(ak+b)\left(-\frac12\right)^k.$$

Plugging in the equation,

$$(ak+a+b)\left(-\frac12\right)\left(-\frac12\right)^k+\frac14(ak+b)\left(-\frac12\right)^k=k\left(-\frac12\right)^k,$$
or
$$-\frac{ak+a+b}2+\frac{ak+b}{4}=k.$$

This works with $a=-4,b=\dfrac83$.

---

You can also work it out by the method of constant variation, setting $x_k=\left(-\frac14\right)^kz_k$, and the equation becomes

$$z_{k+1}\left(-\frac14\right)^{k+1}+\frac14z_k\left(-\frac14\right)^k=k\left(-\frac12\right)^k$$
or
$$z_{k+1}-z_k=-4k2^k.$$

Hence by induction a solution is

$$z_{k+1}=-4\sum_{j=0}^{k}j2^j.$$

The latter expression can be turned to a closed formula, but this approach is less convenient.

Answer (score 0):

May be this solution, thanks to a basis method of solvin :

[image]